# echo a form and some jquery codes

Tags: php, jquery

I would like to post and redirect some values to my path.
I find out the best solution is using a `echo` `form` .

but my code does not work :

```
function goToCodes($method = '' , $tr_ids = '')
{
    $path = base_url().'cart/codes';
    $jquery = base_url().'assests/new/js/jquery.js';

    echo '<form action="'.$path.'" method="post" >';
    echo '<input name="method" type="hidden" value="'.$method.'"  />';
    echo '<input name="tr_ids" type="hidden" value="'.$tr_ids.'"  />';
    echo '<input id="goToCodeSubmit" type="submit"/>';
    echo '</form>';
    echo '<script src="'.$jquery.'"></script>';
    echo '<script>';


    echo '$(function(){
                $(#goToCodeSubmit).click();
         });';

    echo '</script>';


}
```

in the console I get this error :

```
SyntaxError: illegal character
```

[image]

Comment: The selector should be wrapped in quotes `$(#goToCodeSubmit)` ==> `$("#goToCodeSubmit")`

Comment: solved. please post your answer .

Comment: you can use php heredocs. See documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 1):

You should put quotes around your jQuery selector, `$("#goToCodeSubmit")`.

As a side note, without the quotes around `#goToCodeSumit` you're attempting to reference an element by the name `#goToCodeSumit`, which isn't an element in the DOM. Also, the hashtag is probably the thing causing the illegal character error.